# Error when stopping a archive in a active stream

Tags: javascript, opentok

I am using opentok and do I need to stop a archive recording after some time and I succeed in almost all cases, but in some of then, do I have the error below:

"You cannot stop an archive for always archived sessions"

I am using the opentok SDK based on nodeJS, and my archive mode is settled to manual, but was "always" a couple of weeks ago.
The archive begins as soon the stream begins and I do not get any errors, the archive on archive list appears with the "started" status, and other streams inside the list stop without errors.

Someone passed through this and can help me?

Thanks in davance

Comment: Are you using sessions made from the same project API key or different keys?

Comment: Hi! Hope you are well.
I've discovered the reason the error occurs, the session and key are the same, but the archiving was created automatically. 
A archive created this way can't be stopped using API or Opentok archiving methods.
I supressed the stopping for archives created this way, it worked, somehow...

Thanks for answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OpenTok QA staff here,

Auto-archived sessions are, as its own name says, automatically started and stopped, based on connections and publishers, as you can see [Automatically archived sessions](http://%20https://tokbox.com/developer/guides/archiving/#automatic). If you want to have a full control over the archive, use manual archiving.

https://tokbox.com/developer/guides/archiving/#workflow

Comment: Thanks for the informartion, and the documentation, it helped a lot!